# What's the pun in "The wedding is a soft launch"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, pun

source: "For All Mankind" S03E01 00:19:45 / 00:57:22

> ... the stock price for the space tourism company Polaris
> shot through the roof this morning
> as its new hotel hosts the first-ever wedding in space
> for the son of American heroes Gordo and Tracy Stevens.
> **The wedding is a soft launch, pardon the pun**

I only know "soft launch" means "release (a new product or service) to a restricted audience or market in advance of a full launch". I don't see the pun, please enlighten me.

Comment: A wedding in a space capsule will surely have a very small number of guests, which is a 'restricted audience'. Possibly they will have a big party (the 'full launch')  when they get back to Earth.

Answer (score 0):

The wedding led to the stock price's shooting through the roof, as if it is a spacecraft launching off.   The former is hence the soft launch; and the latter, full launch.  The word *launch* is appropriate as it is closely related to the business of the company.

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that Polaris is a **space tourism** company. As you noted, it is a product launch, but they also literally launched the wedding into space, on a craft.